# Sql Server CE 3.1 corruption

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a quite important sdf file, which is corrupted. If I try to open it (password protected, 24 MB) I get the 25017 Error, this is well known and I was be able to fix this Error in the past with `engine.repair` but if i try this, i got a complete System error (not catchable).

Ausnahmecode 0xc0000005
Ausnahmeadresse: 0x017b65d4
Lesen 0x00000064

The same error occurs if i perform `engine.verify` or `engine.compact`
I've tryed to download some desktop sdf viewer, but the all crashed too.

Dit anyone have any idea what's the problem and how to solve? Or am I able to decrypt my databasefile by myself and read the informations with a Text Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing build 8083 or later, and then run Verify/Repair http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-35-sp2-downloadable.html

For 3.0/3.1: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/07/sql-server-2005-compact-edition.html

Comment: yes , I should have mention, that it is a 3.0 sdf, if i try to upgrade it to 3.5 i got the error: 80004005 unknown error

Comment: Added list for 3.1 hotfixes, get the latest and try.

Comment: you are my hero ;) Works perfectly

Comment: Erik,

I have a server side program running on a window server 2003. It is using System.Data.SqlServerCe as well, and it has the same problem on Verify.
 I am wondering what is the right way to use this hotfix?

Thanks